# Referencing package main in a subpackage

Tags: go

new to Golang and have a seemingly simple question. If I have a logger in package main (and defined in `logger.go`) at my project root, how do I reference that logger in a subpackage (ie: my `routes package`)?

My directory structure is:

- main.go
- logger.go
- routes\routes.go
- ...

I would think if Logger is public it would already be available to routes, but I get 'undefined: Logger' in `routes.go`. And if I try to import my main package in `routes.go` I get an 'import cycle not allowed' error since `routes.go` imports package main and `main.go` imports package routes.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to resolve this is to move the shared logger to a third package and import it into both `main` and `routes`. Otherwise you get a cyclic dependency which as you've seen is not allowed.

Simply add a folder called `logger` and put your logger in there. now import it into the other 2 packages, and you're done.

Comment: Hrm, that seems needlessly complex! Do people make packages for every util?

Comment: @KyleChadha Yes. That's what people do and what you should do.

Comment: @KyleChadha the other option would be to keep the routes in the same package of course.