# How to use main package logger at extra package in golang?

Tags: go, logging

I want to make global logger.

Can I make global logger? (To access every pacakges)

Comment: No. You have to explicitly pass it into any package you want it to be usable (either direct or indirect).

Comment: Yes, you can use a global logger (or any other global variable), but you shouldn't. In any case, what have you tried?  Show your code. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I want to use logger in main package at other packages.

Comment: I fount solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375034/referencing-package-main-in-a-subpackage

Answer (score 0):

Packages can have global variables:

```
package somepackage

import "log"

var (
  Log *log.Logger = log.New(os.Stderr, "", log.LstdFlags)
)
```

Notice that I capitalized `Log`. This means it is `exported` (think `public` in other languages).

In general though, using globals is discouraged. I would recommend thinking of a different pattern.